# Lista con Diccionario en C#

Tags: c#

Quiero tratar de hacer un array asociativo en c# así como en php, el código que tengo es este:

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> amigos = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();

public Form1()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     LlenarDiccionario();
}

private void LlenarDiccionario()
{
      dic.Add("nombre", "Pedro");
      dic.Add("apellido", "Nodauna");
      amigos.Add(dic);
      dic.Clear();

      dic.Add("nombre", "Juan");
      dic.Add("paterno", "Caguamas");
      amigos.Add(dic);
      dic.Clear();

      dic.Add("nombre", "Saul");
      dic.Add("apellido", "Martinez");
      amigos.Add(dic);
      dic.Clear();

      dic.Add("nombre", "Manuel");
      dic.Add("apellido", "Chavez");
      amigos.Add(dic);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < amigos.Count; i++)
    {
        var elem = amigos[i];
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(1);
        dataGridView1[0, i].Value = elem["nombre"];
        dataGridView1[1, i].Value = elem["apellido"];
    }
}
```

Cuando quería visualizar la lista me marcaba error:

> el indice nombre no existe

Al revisar me di cuenta que lo que sucedía es que por cada clear que aplicaba después de guardar el diccionario en la lista me eliminaba el diccionario y el diccionario que posteriormente se había guardado en la lista, la pregunta es por que elimina todo?? Que no se supone que el diccionario que esta guardado en la lista es muy aparte del que se crea fuera de la lista??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema esta en      `dic.Clear();` en C# todas las son referencias expecto tipos basicos como el int ...

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> amigos = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

public Form1()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     LlenarDiccionario();
}

private void LlenarDiccionario()
{
      Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
      dic.Add("nombre", "Pedro");
      dic.Add("apellido", "Nodauna");
      amigos.Add(dic);

      dic =  new Dictionary<string, string>();
      dic.Add("nombre", "Juan");
      dic.Add("paterno", "Caguamas");
      amigos.Add(dic);

      dic =  new Dictionary<string, string>();
      dic.Add("nombre", "Saul");
      dic.Add("apellido", "Martinez");
      amigos.Add(dic);

      dic =  new Dictionary<string, string>();
      dic.Add("nombre", "Manuel");
      dic.Add("apellido", "Chavez");
      amigos.Add(dic);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < amigos.Count; i++)
    {
        var elem = amigos[i];
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(1);
        dataGridView1[0, i].Value = elem["nombre"];
        dataGridView1[1, i].Value = elem["apellido"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Pero eso de estar creando instancias para cada "dic" no ocupa espacio en RAM??

Comment: @JorgeAlonso exactamente, lo mismo que pasa en php... o a que te referis?

Comment: @gbianchi entonces aunque se este trabajando desde web también se ocupa espacio en RAM al instanciar objetos??

Comment: Toda estructura de datos o ocupa memoria. Un arreglo asociativo en PHP o una lista de diccionarios en c#.

Comment: @JorgeAlonso por supuesto. En tu caso, se ocupa espacio del servidor pq este devuelve una respuesta renderizada.

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta proporcionada es correcta. Sin embargo, lo que esta mal no es el codigo, es la logica.

Definitivamente al venir de php, estas pensando en un entorno sin objetos, donde lo que vos queres hacer se soluciona mucho mas facil con un objeto que guarde los datos de la persona.

El diccionario podria ser un "array asociativo".. sin embargo ese concepto no existe. Es mas.. guardar el diccionario varias veces en la lista, es un desproposito.

Tu lista, no tiene eso que vos pensas. Si lo ejecutas dentro de por ejemplo Visual Studio, y revisas la variable, vas a ver que fuiste agregando varias veces el mismo diccionario.. no uno nuevo.

Y agregar un diccionario sobre una lista, no es algo que quieras hacer.

Una clase del estilo

```
public class Persona
{
    public nombre;
    public apellido;
}
```

Y luego agregar a la lista

```
Persona p = new Persona;
p.nombre = "juan";
p.apellido = "perez";
amigos.add(p);
```

Daria un resultado muy similar.

Comment: De acuerdo. Muchas veces cuando empezamos en un entorno nuevo queremos utilizar técnicas de donde venimos. La mejor manera es tomarse un pequeño tiempo para aprender la buenas prácticas de cada entorno. Incluso PHP hoy en día es mucho más poderoso que hace algunos años atrás.

Comment: En este caso, mas que las tecnicas es entender que el paradigma de un lenguaje tipado y orientado a objetos es bastante diferente. @AgustinEloyBarrios

Comment: Es cierto. Técnicas, infraestructuras, paradigmas de programación aplicables, disponibilidad de bibliotecas, en fin sacarle provecho.